# How can I evaluate this double integral by using geometry/symmetry?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to evalute this integral. 
$\displaystyle\iint\limits_{D}(2+x^2y^3 - y^2\sin x)\,dA$
$$D=\left \{ (x, y):\left | x \right |+\left | y \right | \leq 1\right \}$$

At first, I evaluated simply by putting $-1\leq x\leq 1, -1\leq y\leq 1$, thus making 
$$ 
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}(2+x^2y^3 - y^2\sin x)\,dx\,dy, 
$$
but the answer I got was 8, not 4, which my answersheed requires me.

Answer (score 2):

You got the wrong answer since your bounds are wrong. The bounds $-1 \le x \le 1$ and $-1 \le y \le 1$ describe the square with vertices $(1,1)$, $(-1,1)$, $(-1,-1)$, and $(1,-1)$.

However, the region $D$ is the square with vertices $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$, and $(0,-1)$. The bounds should be something like $-1 \le y \le 1$ and $-1+|y| \le x \le 1-|y|$.

Of course, there is an easier way to evaluate this integral using symmetry.

Break it up into three pieces:

$\displaystyle\iint\limits_{D}2\,dx\,dy + \iint\limits_{D}x^2y^3\,dx\,dy - \iint\limits_{D}y^2\sin x\,dx\,dy$

The 1st integral is simply twice the area of $D$, which is easy to calculate since $D$ is a square.

Since $x^2y^3$ is odd w.r.t. $y$ and $D$ is symmetric about $y = 0$, the 2nd integral is $0$.

Since $y^2\sin x$ is odd w.r.t. $x$ and $D$ is symmetric about $x = 0$, the 3rd integral is $0$.

Now, put these results together to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the symmetry of $D$, both integrals from $x^2y$ and $y^2\sin x$ are equal to 0. The measure of $D$ is 2, hence the integral is $2|D|=4$.